# Recursive Pre-order Binary Tree Traversal in Python - Nonetype Error

Tags: python, if-statement, recursion, binary-tree

I am having issues with a helper method in my code. I providing both correct and incorrect approaches to the problem but I fail to see the difference between the two.

My approach :

```
def preorder_print(self, start, traversal):
        if start == None:
            return traversal
        else:
            traversal += str(start.value)
            traversal = self.preorder_print(start.left,traversal)
            traversal = self.preorder_print(start.right,traversal)
```

**Note** : *start* is the root node and *traversal* is an empty string

This gives *TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'NoneType' and 'str*'

The correct approach :

```
def preorder_print(self, start, traversal):
        if start:
            traversal += str(start.value) 
            traversal = self.preorder_print(start.left, traversal)
            traversal = self.preorder_print(start.right, traversal)
        return traversal
```

I am unable to understand the difference between these two approaches. Can someone explain how the two approaches differ in execution.

Comment: well.... you need to return `traversal` in the first one ;)

Answer (score 1):

In this answer, we separate preorder traversal logic from the the computation/effect. Starting with a `node` class -

```
class node:
  def __init__(self, data, left = None, right = None):
    self.data = data
    self.left = left
    self.right = right
```

And here's the `tree` class -

```
class tree:
  def __init__(self, root = None):
    self.root = root

  @property
  def is_empty(self):
    return self.root is None

  @property
  def data(self):
    return self.root.data

  @property
  def left(self):
    return self.root.left

  @property
  def right(self):
    return self.root.right

  def preorder(self):
    if not self.is_empty:
      yield self.data
      yield from tree(self.left).preorder()
      yield from tree(self.right).preorder()
```

Let's create a root `node` -

```
root = node \
  ( 1
  , node(2, node(3), node(4))
  , node(5, node(6), node(7))
  )
```

Which represents this tree -

```
      1
     / \
    /   \
   2     5
  / \   / \
 3   4 6   7
```

Now we can `print` the whole tree -

```
for val in tree(root).preorder():
  print(val)

# 1
# 2
# 3
# 4
# 5
# 6
# 7
```

It's important to keep traversal of our tree separate from the computations we make on the tree's values. For example, we can easily `sum` the values -

```
print(sum(tree(root).preorder()))
# 28
```

Or we can collect all of the values in an ordered `list` -

```
print(list(tree(root).preorder()))
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

If `print` is a part of `preorder`, you'll have to duplicate the preorder traversal logic for every other tree operation you wish to implement.

---

**best practice**

You should probably safeguard against accessing properties on an empty node -

```
class tree:

  # ...

  @property
  def data(self):
    if self.is_empty:
      raise Exception("cannot get data of an empty tree")
    else:
      return self.root.data

  @property
  def left(self):
    if self.is_empty:
      raise Exception("cannot get left of an empty tree")
    else:
      return self.root.left

  @property
  def right(self):
    if self.is_empty:
      raise Exception("cannot get right of an empty tree")
    else:
      return self.root.right
```

---

**other traversals**

Now imagine you want to traverse your tree in other ways, such as `inorder` or `postorder`. Mixing computations/effects like `print` or `+` means you will have even *more* duplication. We'll definitely want to avoid that -

```py
class tree:
  # ...
  def inorder(self):
    if not self.is_empty:
      yield from tree(self.left).inorder()
      yield self.data
      yield from tree(self.right).inorder()

  def postorder(self):
    if not self.is_empty:
      yield from tree(self.left).postorder()
      yield from tree(self.right).postorder()
      yield self.data
```

For reference, here's our tree again -

```
      1
     / \
    /   \
   2     5
  / \   / \
 3   4 6   7
```

Here's `inorder` traversal at work -

```
print(list(tree(root).inorder()))
# [3, 2, 4, 1, 6, 5, 7]

print(sum(tree(root).inorder()))
# 28
```

And `postorder` -

```
print(list(tree(root).postorder()))
# [3, 4, 2, 6, 7, 5, 1]

print(sum(tree(root).postorder()))
# 28
```

Comment: Even though the solution to my original problem was simply a missing return statement, I still appreciate the time you took to give this well-researched answer.